# Computed Column - Need help writing statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, calculated-columns

Never heard of computed column until I needed to set one up today so excuse the stupidity. Here is my create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE [Match](

    [Match Org] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Bypass] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [win] as case when [Match Org] == 'yes' or [Bypass] == 'yes' then 'yes' else 'no'

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I want the win column to automatically compute to yes if either match org or bypass have yes in them... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [Match](

    [Match Org] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Bypass] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [win] AS CASE WHEN  ( [Match Org] = 'yes'    --- equality check is:  =
                       OR [Bypass] = 'yes' )     --- not:  ==
                  THEN 'yes' 
                  ELSE 'no'
             END                                 --- END was missing
        PERSISTED             --- you may also want to make
                              --- the column PERSISTED 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [Match]( 

    [Match Org] [nvarchar](10) NULL, 
    [Bypass] [nvarchar](10) NULL, 
    [win] as case  when  [Match Org] = 'yes' or [Bypass] = 'yes' then 'yes' else 'no' end
)

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do is

Columns creation in table

```
[win]  AS ([dbo].[GetColValue]([Match Org],[Bypass ]))
```

Function you can create

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetColValue](@MatchOrg nvarchar(10),@Bypass nvarchar(10))
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Result varchar(10)
        SET @Result = case 
                  when ([Match Org] = 'yes' or [Bypass] = 'yes' )
                  then 'yes' else 'no' 
                  end        
         RETURN 
        (
            @Result
        )
    END
```