# SQL Server : Computed Column DATEDIFF Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, formula, datediff

What I'm trying to do is the following: I have 3 columns (`Control_OpenDate`, `Control_Record Age`, `Control_Stage2`). Once the row is inserted it will populate `Control_OpenDate` (01/27/2013) and `Control_RecordAge` (computed column, see formula).

```
(datediff(day, [Control_OpenDate], getdate()))
```

which gives the days up to date.

Everything is working perfect but I want to add like an `IF` condition to the computed column whenever the column `Control_Stage2` is populated if not, do not calculate or add a text...

*How can I add the `WHERE`-statement in the above formula??*

Note: I'm entering such formula directly into the column properties, I know there are queries that can do this but is there a way to do it trough a formula.

Comment: Show us some code. Have you tried `CASE`?

Comment: `Control_OpenDateOwner` does not exist in your schema as described.

Comment: Sorry, i have corrected the typo.. and well any solution applied to the formula will be greatly appreciated it. FYI i dont have a lot of SQL experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using a `CASE`-statement, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700447/computed-column-need-help-writing-statement).

Your logic will then look like:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN [Control_Stage2] IS NULL THEN NULL -- or -1 or what you like
    ELSE datediff(day,[Control_OpenDate],getdate())
END)
```

Comment: Thank you, i formatted the entire code as a single line to be entered in the column properties. i'm learning from all your feedback (njk,REdfilter, Jacco)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be written as a ternary statement ([IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

*IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )*

IIF is a shorthand way for writing a CASE expression. It evaluates the Boolean expression passed as the first argument, and then returns either of the other two arguments based on the result of the evaluation. That is, the true_value is returned if the Boolean expression is true, and the false_value is returned if the Boolean expression is false or unknown

E.G.

```
iif([Control_Stage2] is null, null, datediff(day,[Control_OpenDate],getdate()))
```